# Create template for crystal report

Tags: asp.net, templates, crystal-reports

I am using crystal report in my asp web application. I would like to develop many reports which have the same design, header ,footer and etc.Did crystal report provide creating any template which can use for other report?Just like master page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Crystal Reports there is the concept on Template; i didn't find it very useful, and used it just to save some chart and use them with the same parameters on other reports.

**For Headers and Footers i use Subreports** instead; it's very easy to import them and to re-import if you want to change the Template

EDIT:

Here is an Example

- Create a Report called `header.rpt`
- put a parameter in the header called `Title`
- insert a `text area` and display `Title` in it
- Crate a Report called `main.rpt`
- Insert `header.rpt` as a sub-report inside `main.rpt`, put it in `Page Header` section
- Pass the report name from `main.rpt` to `header.rpt` using `subreport links`
- enjoy the report!

change the template

- Open `header.rpt` and modyfy it (change the title font, or alignment, or insert an image)
- Open `main.rpt` click `reimport subreport`
- enjoy the report!

Comment: Hi can you give me an example ?Thanks

Comment: Look at the edit; it's not an example but a guide.. is it ok?

Comment: @user998405 great! Good reporting!

Answer (score 0):

I have same query ...but i solved it diff. way ( unofficial way)

I didn't find such way.

Thanks fr question...

Comment: If you want to use particular report design as a template just do it with "" save as "" ...

bt i think Microsoft will do it with VS 201* etc...